# Underscore.js: filter objects with nested array of objs

Tags: javascript, filter, lodash

I am trying to filter top-level objects based on nested data (filtering is also needed for nested objects).

Filter params: All records with categoryValue A.

```
  const table = [
    {
      name: 'Bob',
      detail: [
        { category: 'Employeer', categoryValue: 'A' },
        { category: 'Employeer', categoryValue: 'B' },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'Alice',
      detail: [
        { category: 'Employeer', categoryValue: 'C' },
        { category: 'Employeer', categoryValue: 'D' },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

I am expecting the following result

```
  const fileredTable = [

    { 
      //this
      name: 'Bob',
      detail: [
        //and only this
        { category: 'Employeer', categoryValue: 'A' }

      ],
    }
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after several tries i found this solution:

```
const filteredTable = table.flatMap((item) => {
  const filteredDetail = item.detail.filter((e) => e.categoryValue === 'A')
  return filteredDetail.length !== 0 ? {...item, detail: filteredDetail} :  []
})
```